# How can I manipulate database results to add links to my Gridview?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, url, gridview

I have a GridView that I use to display the results of a query that I craft and execute in a asp.net code-behind file. The trouble is, I have one of the columns return a rather long URL. I would rather display this is the gridview as an image or text with an anchor tag wrapped around it, with the original link.

How do I do this such that I have the same image on every row of the column, but different URLs depending on what was originally returned to me?

Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"  DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" >
        <Columns>
            <asp:HyperLinkField HeaderText="Header"
               Text ="TextYouWantToAppearOnColumn"
               DataNavigateUrlField="FieldNameFromDataSource" 
               DataNavigateUrlFormatString="http://{0}" />
        </Columns>
  </asp:GridView>
```

If hyperlink is enough for you without image, above solution should work for you. `{0}` is the value from database, you can format the url in any way you want. In this case, I assumed it is an external url to the website without `htpp://`, that is why i added it.

Comment: Thanks for that. I could not set DataTextField to "Link", it had to match the column name from the data source. Any ideas?

Comment: So it turns out you can use either Text (to have all links look the same, but lead to different URLs) or you can use DataTextField (to use the same value returned from the data source). Please update your answer so I can mark it as the right one =) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlinkfield.text.aspx